# How do I correct the range in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is a jsfiddle of the chart I am trying to implement:
https://jsfiddle.net/aaz15/3msqnuk2/

The problem is that I am unable to display the chart correctly, and I believe it has something to do with the range of x. I got inspired by the following :http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967.

The problem I think is in this line:

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", x.range()) //here
```

The range is already defined for x, and `rangeband()` in the original implementation got deprecated in favor of `range()` and other modifications.
How do I fix this problem? any hints or suggestions is highly appreciated :)

Comment: It's done with `scaleBand` and `bandwidth()`. But, before anything, check your `layers`... you won't go anywhere with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have empty array about `layers`. So, it is right the rects were not showing.

But as you said, the ticks are not evenly divided by the problem of `x`'s range.

[fixed fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3msqnuk2/2/)

I've just fixed the method changed from v3 to v4.

```
// your scale
var x = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(d3.range(m))
  .range([0, width], .08);

// it should be changed to..
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(m))
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(.08);
```

`scaleBand`'s methods are not parts of `scaleOrdinal` any more since v4.

It might be comprehensive information to take a look differences between [v3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#ordinal_rangeRoundBands) and [v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#band-scales) methods.